# Where does brew search search for local taps?

Tags: homebrew

I did a `brew search ocaml` which results in `==> Searching local taps...
ocaml  ocamlbuild  ocamlsdl`.  I had removed ocaml from my system, yet it's showing up in the search for local taps. I've tried `brew cleanup -s` and `brew doctor` but it didn't fix it.  Thoughts?

Comment: What’s the issue there? `brew search ocaml` tells you there’s a formula for `ocaml`; not that it’s installed on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taps are sources of formulae. A formula is a file that describes how to install software. The main tap is `homebrew/core` but anybody can create one. Taps are managed with the `brew tap` and `brew untap` commands.

When Homebrew tells you it’s "`searching local taps`", it means it’s looking for an `ocaml` formula in one of the taps you have locally. If one of the formula it finds is installed locally, it’ll show it in bold with a little checkmark next to it:

```
# OCaml is installed
$ brew search ocaml
==> Searching local taps...
ocaml ✔  ocamlbuild  ocamlsdl

# Ocaml is NOT installed
$ brew search ocaml
==> Searching local taps...
ocaml  ocamlbuild  ocamlsdl
```

As you can see in your case, you don’t get that checkmark so Ocaml is not installed. You can be sure by typing `brew info ocaml`:

```
$ brew info ocaml
ocaml: stable 4.05.0 (bottled), HEAD
General purpose programming language in the ML family
https://ocaml.org/
Not installed  <--------- look here
...
```

---

As for taps you can list those you have locally using `brew tap`:

```
$ brew tap
homebrew/core
homebrew/services
homebrew/fuse
homebrew/nginx
homebrew/php
...
```

The exact output may vary but you’ll always have at least `homebrew/core`.

To add a new tap, use `brew tap <tap>`:

```
 brew tap homebrew/science
```

To remove a tap, use `brew untap <tap>`:

```
 brew untap homebrew/science
```

Note you can’t remove `homebrew/core`.